# Paperclip photo.url not working in Backbone.js

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, paperclip

I tried to display the images in Backbone.js view page.

My show_view.js.coffee is

```
Myapp.Views.Checklists ||= {}

class Myapp.Views.Checklists.ShowView extends Backbone.View
 template: JST["backbone/templates/checklists/show"]

render: ->
 @$el.html(@template(@model.toJSON() ))
 return this
```

My show.jst.ejs file is

```
<p>
<b>Title:</b>
<%= title %>
</p>

<p>
<img src="<%= how_to_show_photo_url %>" alt="No image">

</p>

<a href="#/index">Back</a>
```

I am using paperclip gem. I tried using <%= photo.url %> in image tag but it is not working. How do I show the photo in image tag?

Comment: What's the name of your attribute/property in your `Model` that contains the Url? Use that. (Is it `photo.url`?)

Comment: @model.toJSON() gives {"comments":"Backbone attachment","created_at":"2013-03-12T23:41:40Z","id":16,"photo_content_type":"image/jpeg","photo_file_name":"IMG_0011.JPG","photo_file_size":2714495,"photo_updated_at":"2013-03-12T23:41:40Z","title":"Test Attaachment using backbone","updated_at":"2013-03-12T23:41:40Z"}. Since I m using paperclip, I tried <%= photo.url %>

Comment: `<%= photo_file_name %>` looks like the file name. I don't understand where you're getting `photo.url` from? It's not one of the properties of the object returned from the server. Your template only has access to the properties and objects that you send it explicitly via the compiled template function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I altered the response in rails before sending it to backbone.js. I updated the photo_file_name attribute with original path of the file. I updated the code as

```
@checklists = Checklist.find(:all)
@checklists.map{|k,v| k.photo_file_name = k.photo.url }
```

Now my Json response is

```
{"comments":"Backbone attachment","created_at":"2013-03-12T23:41:40Z","id":16,"photo_content_type":"image/jpeg",
"photo_file_name":"/system/checklists/photos/000/000/016/original/IMG_0011.JPG?1363131700",
"photo_file_size":2714495,"photo_updated_at":"2013-03-12T23:41:40Z","title":"Test Attaachment using backbone","updated_at":"2013-03-12T23:41:40Z"}
```

I used photo_file_name attribute in image src tag

Any better solutions are most welcome

Comment: I think this is the best way to do this.